# OpenCV SVD Matrix format

Tags: matrix, opencv, svd

I currently have a set of 2D Cartesian coordinates e.g. {(1,3), (2,2), (3,4)}
Which will be put into a 2D array, to perform SVD properly would the matrix be put together such that the coordinates form the columns or the rows e.g.

```
1 3
2 2
3 4
```

or

```
1 2 3
3 2 4
```

I have been doing a little trial and error comparing to examples of SVD I have found online, the resulting matrix usually seems to be negated, with some of the values shuffled around.

To clarify further if I had a matrix E which was MxN as shown here http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Matrix.svg

To define the matrix as a 2D array would it be Array[M][N] or Array[N][M]

I am assuming this actually matters due to matrix arithmetic not being commutative? Can anyone actually  verify this?

Answer (score -1):

[This link](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/matrix/index.htm) describes how to create a matrix from a set of vectors

> In order to create a matrix by
>   compounding vector like structures we
>   need to do two things to the 'inner
>   vector':
>
> > We need to take the transpose so that
> >     it is a row rather than a column.
> >
> > We need a multiplication operation which
> >     will make it a field.

However this does not clarify the standards used for OpenCV and SVD.